# Can I box gravity into an SKSpriteNode in SKSpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics, gravity, skspritenode

Is it possible to set gravity and full physics inside of an SKNode?

I'd like to have a boxed area with sprites inside that react to the gravity within the box no matter how the box is transformed. So jumping, falling, etc would be relative to the "floor" of the box no matter the rotation of the box itself.

Possible? If yes, How?

thanks,
rich

Comment: Will you have physics bodies affected by gravity which are outside the box as well? If not, it's as simple as setting the world gravity to the inverse normal of the floor whenever the floor's rotation changes. Otherwise it can work by setting world gravity to 0, and apply impulse (aka gravity, again in the direction of the floor's normal inverse) to every body based on whether it's inside or outside the box.

Comment: Yes I will have gravity in other areas. the idea is similar to Angry Birds Star Wars - the levels with the gravity elements. When a sprite moves within range of a gravity element, that gravity kicks in and pulls that sprite towards it.

Comment: Also, can I change the self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0) to other values at different times? For example if my sprite moves within the bounds of another sprite, can I check the world gravity vector at that time?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in any simple one liner of code. One option would be to check for any node's coordinates to be inside the box and apply the desired force on the nodes. You can use a maximum force applied check to cap it at the desired level.

Comment: So apply an impulse at a 90 deg to the box floor rotation? or is there a force property I can set like a magnet?

Comment: @user2887097 - you will have to apply a force to all objects within the box in the direction of your choice.